# download a file through SSL in C

Tags: c, ssl

I have to write a SSL client in C that connects to a server,and gets either a html,either a file. I managed to get the html,but i can't download a binary file. For example,i'm trying to download a 3.8mb file from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0d.tar.gz and my code only manages to download 1.1mb of them,and i don't even know if i get the right data in it.

Here is the function that i made for it:

```
char *sslReadfile (connection *c)
{
  const int readSize = 1024;
  char *rc = NULL;
  int received, count = 0;
  char buffer[1024];
  char filename[40];
  printf("Input the file name to be saved:\n");
  scanf("%s",filename);
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

  if (c)
    {
      while (1)
        {
          if (!rc)
            rc = malloc (readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);
          else
            rc = realloc (rc, readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);

          received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);
          buffer[received] = '\0';

          if (received > 0)
            fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);//strcat (rc, buffer);

          if (received < readSize)
            break;
          //count++;
        }
    }
  printf("\nFile saved!! %s !!!\n\n",filename);
  fclose(fp);
  return rc;
}
```

oh, and i call it like that:

```
char command[50];
sprintf(command,"GET /%s\r\n\r\n",relativepath);
sslWrite (c, command);
response = sslReadfile (c);
```

where c is my connection.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `fprintf` to write binary data.  Use `fwrite`.  The reason your output is smaller is that `fprintf` is stopping at the first null character, skipping any characters that remain in the 1024 byte buffer.  Also, you don't appear to be using, and don't need the `malloc`d `rc` buffer.

So, after the call to `SSL_read`, you want something like this:

```
if (received <= 0) break;
fwrite(buffer, 1, received, fp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.You solved my problem :) And thanks to Mel too,the answer below,i shouldn't break that loop when received<readSize :)

Answer (score 1):

You break the loop when received < readSize, instead you should only break the loop when received <= 0 and you have inspected `SSL_shutdown()` and/or `SSL_get_error()`.
Also, you shouldn't NUL terminate your buffer and use `fprintf`, but keep the buffer as is while using `fwrite`. You are now introducing NULs in your data that weren't there.